# Trying to install CentOS with Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, centos6.5

I have virtualbox running on Mac OSX. After going through the initial install of CentOS 6.5 I get the message to reboot. If I do not remove the cd from virtual drive It will again bring the initial livecd user environment. If I click remove cd from virtual drive I get "Invalid or corrupt kernel image" error. How do I correctly remove the iso to continue the install after reboot? Thank you.

Comment: You should ask this on http://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I needed to use the dvd iso instead of the live cd. The live provides a different install wizard than the one from the dvd iso. The live cd install does not include the button "reboot". The dvd iso did. Installed no problem.